# How can I find the Jordan form of this upper triangular Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, toeplitz-matrices

> Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ whose $(i,j)$ entry is
>
> $$a_{ij} = \begin{cases} n-j+i & \text{if } j \geq i\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> find its Jordan form.

I know that all the Jordan blocks will have $\lambda = n$ as eigenvalue, but how can I find the size of each block?

Comment: Have you tried it for $n=2,3,4$ ?

Comment: @lhf I tried for n=2,3 and it looks like there will be only one block.

Comment: Anyone can help please?

Comment: The **number** of Jordan blocks equals the number of linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $n$. Solve the equation $Av=n v$

Comment: @Lozenges do you mean this is equal to dim(ker(A-lambda*I))? If so, why is this true?

Comment: Yes. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) for an explanation. In your example there is one Jordan block